# Firebase custom claims is not actually setting for me - Python backend

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, firebase

Right now this is the code I am using to set the custom claim called "moderator":

```py
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import auth

cred = credentials.Certificate(r".\sa.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

EMAIL = "bearcodes@outlook.com"
user = auth.get_user_by_email(EMAIL)

uid = "H9c1PQtSHxZfV3AWW5pQjNlSDnX2" # This is for bearcodes@outlook.com (this is of course an example)

auth.set_custom_user_claims(uid, {'moderator': True})
```

When I run it, there are no errors and it says nothing.

My cloud firestore rules are as follows:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /pupils/{document=**} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
    
    match /cclaims/{claims} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow write: if request.auth.token.moderator == true;
    }
  }
}
```

However when I run this simulated test (via the console) while logged into the website, it produces the error: `Error writing document:  FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

This is the "simulated test" that I ran:

```js
function testccl() {
    db.collection("cities").doc("LA").set({
        name: "Los Angeles",
        state: "CA",
        country: "USA"
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Document successfully written!");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
    });   
}
```

Thanks in advance and I look forward to hearing your answer(s).

-The SimsRedux Team

Comment: Nope :) That is a completely diff error.

Comment: Can you explain "via the console" then? You should be logged in as that moderator user to pass those rules.

Comment: e.g I was already logged in using firebase auth so through console I just invoked the testccl() function so I didnt have to hook it up to any frontend

Comment: Yes it doesn't work :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236517/discussion-between-psuedo-and-dharmaraj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test function, write to the `claims` collection, you may need to reload and get a new token with the moderator claim as well.